# Cluster products that are frequently bought together

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, recommender-system

I have a dataset of articles metadata for each article, so something like this:

| product_id | color | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | red | t-shirt |

and another containing the transactions of customers, which looks like this:

| date | customer_id | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/12/12 | abcd | 1234 |

Using the second dataset, I was able to determine which products are often bought together. As such, for each product, I have a sorted list of 10 (different) products (at most, it could be less) that are most frequently bought with it. This information is stored in a dictionary of the following form:

```
{1234: [5678,6352,3434,34433, ...], 1435 : [7832, 9801, 1234], ...}
```

**My question is the following**. Is there a way for me to create embeddings of products such that a given product is "close" to the products it is most frequently bought with ? In other words, I want to cluster articles that are bought together in a space and have vectors (embeddings) for each product.

Why would I want to do this ?

1. To see if I can see an interesting structure in my data
2. To recommend items to users, I can look for the k-nearest neighbors of the users' latest purchases

It looks to me like it is some form of supervised clustering (if that even makes sense), but I can't exactly find how I would go about doing this.

If you could point to me towards an algorithm or something I am missing here, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is a straightforward use case for [collaborative filtering](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/recommendation/collaborative/basics).

1. Transform your customer transactions dataset so that you have a matrix where each row is a customer, each column is a product, and the value of each cell is 1 of that customer has bought that product, and 0 otherwise.
2. Train a collaborative filtering model on your data. This will result in one matrix with a vector per customer, and another matrix with a vector per product.
3. Cluster the vectors from the product matrix.

Caveat: this method does not leverage any of the information in your articles metadata table.